# Android calendar create kind of recursion

Tags: android, recursion, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I have a problem with adding event to Google Calendar programmaticly.

Here is code:

```
private void addToGoogleCalendar(long beginTime) {
    ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
    Observable.from(dataKeeper.getCalendarIds().keySet()).filter(key -> dataKeeper.getCalendarIds().get(key).equals(defaultCalendarName.getText().toString())).forEach(key ->
            event.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.CALENDAR_ID, Integer.parseInt(key))
    );

    event.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.TITLE, reminderName.getText().toString());

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(commentEdittext.getText().toString()))
        event.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.DESCRIPTION, commentEdittext.getText().toString());

    event.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
    event.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.DTSTART, beginTime);
    event.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.DTEND, dataKeeper.getEnd());
    event.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.EVENT_COLOR, getResources().getColor(R.color.primary));

    // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2445
    if (dataKeeper.getPeriod() > 0 && dataKeeper.getPeriod() != 7)
        event.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.RRULE, String.format("FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=%d;UNTIL=%s", dataKeeper.getPeriod() - 1,
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.getDefault()).format(dataKeeper.getEnd())));
    else if (dataKeeper.getPeriod() == 7)
        event.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.RRULE, String.format("FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;UNTIL=%s",
                new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd", Locale.getDefault()).format(dataKeeper.getEnd())));

    event.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.ALL_DAY, 1); // 0 for false, 1 for true
    event.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.STATUS, CalendarContract.Events.STATUS_CONFIRMED);

    String eventUriString = "content://com.android.calendar/events";
    getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse(eventUriString), event);
}
```

Inrerval = 1

So, when I add event, it adds as need, but in few seconds I see that event adds recursive. First day one time, next day two times and so on.

Method called only ones, so I have no idea WTF happens.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set the end of the master instance to the end of the recurrence rule.

The first instance has a duration of `dataKeeper.getEnd() - beginTime`. According to the `RRULE` this instance is recurs every day until `dataKeeper.getEnd()`

Now if `dataKeeper.getEnd()` is several days after `beginTime` it happens that although the fist instance is still ongoing on the second day (because it has a duration of multiple days), another instance starts on that day.

On the third day, the first two instances are still ongoing and the rule says another one should start.

So there is one instance added until the `UNTIL` date of the `RRULE`, after that the number of instances decreases by one each day.

To fix it make sure that the first instance is just a day long. Replace

```
event.put(CalendarContract.Reminders.DTEND, dataKeeper.getEnd());
```

by

```
event.put(CalendarContract.Events.DURATION, "P1D");
```

This sets the duration of each instance to 1 day. You should always use `DURATION` for recurring events anyway, see [Events](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html).

Btw, you should also use `CalendarContract.Events` instead of `CalendarContract.Reminders`. Although `Reminders` also implements `EventsColumns` it's meant for alarms. I guess it contains the event columns because it effectively reads from a join over both tables.